# destroying ctrl object in scope angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, memory-leaks

In my controller, I always use `var ctrl = this;` and then use `ctrl` to attach functions, variables, etc (instead of scope). So I would have this in my controller:

`ctrl.showButton = function() { /* some code */ };`

and my question is: I tried to print my $scope object using console.log during `$scope.$on('$destroy')` and I notice that my scope has this object still even though it's on destroy (see the `ctrl: Object` part)

[image]

Maybe I don't understand the concept clearly, but do I have to clear this object on destroy? Will it get cleaned up by Angular like the watchers?
Thanks.

Comment: It depends on what exactly is going on in showButton. Generally you shouldn't care about destroy.

Comment: @matthewpavkov I undeleted it :) I was thinking to use another container to make it like a frame for each page and nest an ng-repeat but your suggestion is better I think, I'll tweak it a bit for my own purpose. Can you post an answer and I'll mark it as an answer.